# Register UTI for file extension associated with dynamic UTI

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, uti

Suppose an NSDocument based application defined an exported file type without specifying a UTI for it, resulting in a dynamic UTI being set by macOS for those files. Simply declaring a UTI in the app doesn’t seem to affect newly written files, the dynamic UTI is still used. Is there any way to set a new UTI for the application to use for this file kind?

Comment: Simplest solution is to look into Info.plist files inside Application folder (how others do it). You might need also some kind of indexing refresh as well.

Comment: This should help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47319/how-can-i-make-os-x-recognize-new-file-extensions